# Publisher js function not working with custom email publisher

Tags: publisher-action, spring15

In a nutshell the issue is, We've implemented custom email publisher action where we are using publisher js. We are populating email body with the response received with publisher js but its not getting updated. It was working fine till  API version 32 but since version 33 its breaking.

Some more pointers on the events which we see while calling this functionality. It looks specific to Custom Publisher action called Send_Email on Case object which contains a visualforce page that has `apex:emailPublisher` tags.

Following are the javascript events that works on Winter 15 and doesnt work on Spring 15

Winter 15 :

```
CEB EVENT! ns<entityFeed:publisher> en<onShow> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<1>

Chatter.js:257 CEB EVENT! ns<action:Case.Email> en<onSetInputValues> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<1>

Chatter.js:257 CEB EVENT! ns<entityFeed:publisher> en<onShow> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<0>

Chatter.js:257 CEB EVENT! ns<entityFeed:publisher> en<onShow> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<0>

Chatter.js:257 CEB EVENT! ns<action:Case.Email> en<onSetInputValues> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<9>
Chatter.js:257 CEB EVENT! ns<action:Case.Email> en<onSetInputValues> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<0>
```

Spring 15 :

```
CEB EVENT! ns<entityFeed:publisher> en<onShow> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<4>

Chatter.js:257 CEB EVENT! ns<entityFeed:publisher> en<onShow> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<0>

EntityFeedCore.js:17 CEB EVENT! ns<entityFeed:publisher> en<onShow> pld<[object Object]> exec-time<1>

Chatter.js:257 CEB EVENT! ns<entityFeed:publisher> en<onShow> pld<[object Object]> exec-time
```

Has any one faced such issue or have any pointer on this? Has salesforce changed/introduced anything new around it?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered a similar issue with a custom VF console component that when clicked would populate the standard email publisher with a template. It was working before the Spring '15 release and stopped right after.

We are using the publisher.js "emailFields.template" option to pass in an ID.

What I realized is that we had previously hidden the standard "select a template" option on the publisher, since users would never manually select a template. Having this option hidden was what broke our code though! If you add it back to the publisher, the "emailFields.template" option will work again!

The setting is under Case -> Page Layouts -> Feed View -> Select Email Tools:

[image]